# How to get the row_count using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data structure

```
ID Number   Product_Description
45452       MSSQL
45453       INFORMATICA
45454       INFORMATICA
45458       INFORMATICA
45456       MSSQL
45457       DBA
```

and the output should be

```
MSSQL        2
INFORMATICA  3
DBA          1
```

And I want to store it in a list:

```
v_1 = [MSSQL,INFORMATICA,DBA]
v_2 = [2,3,1]
```

Comment: Please update your question using the formatting tools. You will get much better help if you show what you've tried; StackOverflow is not a code writing forum. Please show your work.

Comment: @user8195447 can you add what type of data structures these are above? I'm pretty sure they are `pandas` `series` (`pd.Series`) objects where `ID Number` is the `Index.name`?

Answer (score 3):

you can use value_counts

```
p=df['Product_Description'].value_counts()
V_1=p.index.tolist()
V_2=p.values.tolist()
```

Comment: beat me to it. this is the best option.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with `sort=False` if order is important:

```
s = df.groupby('Product_Description', sort=False).size()
print (s)
Product_Description
MSSQL          2
INFORMATICA    3
DBA            1
dtype: int64

v_1 = s.index.tolist()
v_2 = s.values.tolist()

print (v_1)
['MSSQL', 'INFORMATICA', 'DBA']
print (v_2)
[2, 3, 1]
```

If order should be different, e.g. [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) ordering by number of occurencies:

```
s = df['Product_Description'].value_counts()
print (s)
INFORMATICA    3
MSSQL          2
DBA            1
Name: Product_Description, dtype: int64

v_1 = s.index.tolist()
v_2 = s.values.tolist()

print (v_1)
['INFORMATICA', 'MSSQL', 'DBA']

print (v_2)
[3, 2, 1]
```

Another solution is create dictionary of lists:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Product_Description', sort=False).size().reset_index()
df1.columns=['v_1','v_2']
print (df1)
           v_1  v_2
0        MSSQL    2
1  INFORMATICA    3
2          DBA    1

d = df1.to_dict(orient='list')
print (d)
{'v_1': ['MSSQL', 'INFORMATICA', 'DBA'], 'v_2': [2, 3, 1]}

print (d['v_1'])
['MSSQL', 'INFORMATICA', 'DBA']

print (d['v_2'])
[2, 3, 1]
```